# 'str' object has no attribute '\_meta' error throughs when i want to put data from form to database

Tags: django

I want to get data from the form but somehow I didn't get as I required plz help me to reach out at my required answer

```py
    from django.db import models
    class Profile(models.Model):
        name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
        address=models.CharField(max_length=100)
        pin=models.CharField(max_length=100)
        contact=models.CharField(max_length=100)
        email=models.CharField(max_length=100)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

```py
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from .models import Profile

    def index(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            name = request.POST.get('name')
            address =request.POST.get('address')
            pin = request.POST.get('pin')
            contact = request.POST.get('contact')
            email = request.POST.get('email','')
            profile = Profile(name="name",address="address",pin="pin",contact="contact",email="email")  
            profile.save()
        return render(request , 'index.html')
```

As you can see , I am trying to put my form's data to the model but it throughs an error "'str' object has no attribute '_meta'"

Comment: Please post the full error message with traceback.

Answer (score 1):

You should intiailise the actual form data as variable names, not as strings, so use the following view:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        address =request.POST.get('address')
        pin = request.POST.get('pin')
        contact = request.POST.get('contact')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        profile = Profile(name=name,address=address,pin=pin,contact=contact,email=email)  
        profile.save()
    return render(request , 'index.html',)
```

Comment: same error is throughing again. i have been struggling for last two days plz give me usefull code .